# Nonnegative determinant matrix as a sum of two squares

Tags: linear-algebra

As one can see in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3033122/is-deta2-i-always-non-negative) MSE question, we have $\det(A^{2} + B^{2})\geq 0$ for any real $n\times n$ matrices $A, B$. Is the converse true? i.e. if a real $n\times n$ matrix with $\det C\geq 0$, is given, can we always find $A, B$ such that $C = A^{2} + B^{2}$?

Also, I'm curious if $\det(A^{2} + B^{2} +C^{2})\geq 0$ is also true for any matrices $A, B, C$, since in this case, we can't apply the same trick as in the previous question.

Comment: The question you have quoted does not tell you that $det(A^{2}+B^{2}) \geq 0$ for all $A$ and $B$. If $AB=BA$ then this is correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Oh I see...but I can't find any counterexample for now