# Polynomial with no real roots implies that $\det(P(A))\ge 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, determinant

Let $P \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ be a polynomial of degree $n$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$, which has no real roots. If $A\in \mathcal{M_n(\mathbb{R})}$, then prove that $\det(P(A))\ge 0$.
I don't know how to approach the general case, but for $n=2$ I was able to prove this by using the canonical form of a quadratic. However, I don't think that this can be generalised to any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and I don't have any other approaches to this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $P$ is real and has no real roots we see that $n$ is even. Since $A$ is real
we see that it has an even number of real eigenvalues and the remainder are conjugate pairs.

If $R$ are the indices of the real eigenvalues of $A$ then we see that
$\Pi_{k \in R} P(\lambda_k) >0$ (since there are an even number) and if $\lambda_k$ is not real,
 we see that
$P(\lambda_k) P(\overline{\lambda_k}) = P(\lambda_k) \overline{ P(\lambda_k) } = |P(\lambda_k)|^2$. Hence $\det P(A) \ge 0$.

Comment: $A$ may have simple real eigenvalues. Yet, $n$ is even...

Comment: Oops, I need to delete & fix

Comment: Is there really an issue? As $n$ must be even, the sign of the determinant is unchanged under scalar multiplication, so one may assume the leading coefficient is $1$ and therefore that $P(x)>0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Then $P(\lambda)>0$ for all real eigenvalues $\lambda$ and the argument for the conjugate pairs is fine, right?

Comment: @J.G: You are correct, but I had incorrectly assumed that $A$ has no real roots which was unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Since $P(x)=0$ has not any real roots, its roots must occur in conjugate pairs. Hence we may write $P(x)=\prod_{i=1}^m(x-z_i)(x-\overline{z}_i)$ for some complex numbers $z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_m$. It follows that
\begin{aligned}
\det P(A)
&=\det\prod_i(A-z_iI)(A-\overline{z}_iI)\\
&=\det\prod_i(A-z_iI)(\overline{A-z_iI})\\
&=\prod_i\det(A-z_iI)\det(\overline{A-z_iI})\\
&=\prod_i\det(A-z_iI)\,\overline{\det(A-z_iI)}\\
&=\prod_i|\det(A-z_iI)|^2\ge0.
\end{aligned}